# SVG Skips/Jitters On Repeat

Tags: xml, animation, svg, vector-graphics

I made a simple SVG which has elements that repeat every 5s, however in every browser and OS I've viewed it in it seems to briefly jump back a few pixels every time it repeats (once 5 dashed lines have exited the frame). It's kinda subtle, but if you look closely it's there.

The code is below and here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/MityaDSCH/pen/vOpbdb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
<!ENTITY st "fill:none;stroke:#000000;">]>
<svg version="1.1" id="feynman-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="700px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 700 600" style="border: 1px solid black;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;position:absolute;margin:auto;enable-background:new 0 0 700 600;" xml:space="preserve">

  <!-- MW line -->
  <polyline style="&st;" points="0,600 200,200 300,400 400,200 500,400 700,0"/>    

  <!-- Top Dashed Line -->    
  <clipPath id="top-dashed-clip">
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="200" fill="url(#Gradient)"/>
  </clipPath>
  <line style="&st;" stroke-dasharray="22, 22" x1="100" y1="0" x2="300" y2="400" clip-path="url(#top-dashed-clip)">
    <animate attributeName="x1" from="100" to="0" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" from="0" to="-200" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="x2" from="300" to="200" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y2" from="400" to="200" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>

  <!-- Bottom Dashed Line -->    
  <clipPath id="bottom-dashed-clip">
    <rect x="500" y="400" width="100" height="200"/>
  </clipPath>
  <line style="&st;" stroke-dasharray="22, 22" x1="600" y1="600" x2="400" y2="200" clip-path="url(#bottom-dashed-clip)">
    <animate attributeName="x1" from="600" to="700" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" from="600" to="800" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="x2" from="400" to="500" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y2" from="200" to="400" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the distance you are moving your dashed lines is 223.6, (sqrt(100^2 + 200^2)), and that is not a multiple of your dash pattern length (44).  So when the animation reaches the end and repeats, there is a jump.

If you adjust your dasharray so it is closer to an even fraction of the length, the jump will disappear.

```
stroke-dasharray="22.36, 22.36"
```

By the way, there is a lot simpler way to do your animation.  Instead of moving the line and hiding the overflow with a clipPath, just animate the `stroke-dashoffset`. See below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" []>
<svg version="1.1" id="feynman-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="700px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 700 600" style="border: 1px solid black;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;position:absolute;margin:auto;"
xml:space="preserve">

  <!-- MW line -->
  <polyline style="fill:none;stroke:#000000" points="0,600 200,200 300,400 400,200 500,400 700,0" />

  <!-- Top Dashed Line -->
  <line style="fill:none;stroke:#000000" stroke-dasharray="22.36, 22.36" x1="100" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="223.6" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </line>

  <!-- Bottom Dashed Line -->
  <line style="fill:none;stroke:#000000" stroke-dasharray="22.36, 22.36" x1="600" y1="600" x2="500" y2="400" clip-path="url(#bottom-dashed-clip)">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="223.6" dur="7s" begin="0s" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </line>

</svg>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this was driving me insane. And thank you for the simplification too!